# Why does Mist contain ffmpeg.dll?

Tags: mist

I've got Norton Antivirus running on my PC and it has been dutifully disabling some files that it detects in the Mist download when I unzip it. In re-enabling these files, I noticed that ffmpeg.dll got detected and disabled. That's an MPEG library, just curious why it was included in Mist. Audio?

Comment: just curious why antivirus flags the mpeg library.

Comment: I've also curious why ffmpeg.so or dll has included.
Is there any function used with OpenCL. GPU functions?
Good questions.

Answer (score 4):

ffmpeg lib is not due to Mist but to chromium that holds the Mist Dapp.

Mist is a web application (html/JS/CSS) packaged within a Chromium browser as a single executable for more convenience. But in a near future, you will probably be able to use Mist to run any Dapp.

Have a look at LICENSES.chromium.html at the root of Ethereum Wallet archive and you'll notice that ffmpeg licence is listed here.

Now, why [chromium includes ffmpeg is because it's used to read mpeg videos from html `<video>` tag](https://www.chromium.org/audio-video).